# Menu order not being honoured

Tags: android, menu, navigation

I have some menu items defined in the `main.xml` file as such:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_edit_friends"
    android:title="@string/menu_edit_friends_label">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_logout"
    android:title="@string/menu_logout_label">
</item>
```

In the `MainActivity` class, I have the following code in the `onOptionsItemSelected` method:

```
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == R.id.action_edit_friends) {
        //Start a new activity
    } else if(id == R.id.action_logout) {
        //Log the user out
```

However, the problem is: Whenever I tap on `action_edit_friends`, the code for `action_logout` is executed and vice-versa. Any clues as to why this is happening? I have cleaned the project, to no avail.

Comment: Are the `Strings` for your titles correct? or are they flipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:orderInCategory="1"`, like this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_go_right"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/menu_go_right"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_go_left"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/menu_go_left"/>
```

If your strings are in fact correct, this won't solve the problem, but it can at least order the items on your menu. Android will rebuild the R file when you recompile the xml, anyway. If the problem persists try changing the action id's to be different in the xml and Java code.